# ArcGIS file geodatabase lock issues

Tags: arcgis

Currently, our workforce has about 15 users who all view the same file geodatabases. Typically, when viewing the data only, a schema lock (sr.lock) is created for whichever feature class is being viewed inside of the geodatabase.  Here lately, one of the users has been creating both a schema lock and a read lock (rd.lock) on the same feature classes.  However, it does not do this for all feature classes being viewed. I can start an editing session on the geodatabase in which the read lock is created, and it will create my editing locks (ed.lock) and allow me to edit just fine like normal. It's only when I go to save my work that "a lock cannot be acquired". It at this point will not allow me to save my edits like normal. What would be causing just a few feature layers to be creating the random read locks on top of the schema locks?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have found your answer.  In case you have not, we encountered the same problem.  Turns out that if any one of the users on a mutually used Feature Class OPENS the TABLE it creates the rd.lock file.  This is what prevents others' from SAVING their edits.  Our solution has been to ask neighbors if they have that particular table open, if so, Close JUST the table, then the editor can save his/her edits.  I hope this helps; I know it is a massive headache, but this solution has worked for us thus far.